# Kotlin: Why can't I use one of my functions?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to use one of my defined functions that accepts a string yet the software won't compile.

```
fun passes(address: String) = Collections.frequency(addresses, address) <= CONNECTIONS_PER_IP

fun passes(remoteAddress: InetSocketAddress) = passes(remoteAddress.hostName)
```

[image: The error]

I can't even call the string function using a custom string, for example `passes("127.0.0.1")`.

[image: The error with a custom string]

```
None of the following functions can eb called with the arguments supplied.

passes(String) defined in abendigo.Firewall
passes(InetSocketAddress) defined in abendigo.Firewall
```

Comment: What does the warning say, the one in the declaration of `passes(address: String)`?

Comment: It is best if you put error messages as text and not just as an image.  It will help others with the same error to find the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you're using `java.lang.String` instead of `kotlin.String` in the Kotlin source code. Please use only `kotlin.String` instead, this is the type that string literals in Kotlin have (but in the bytecode it's still transformed to `java.lang.String`).

Answer (score 2):

The issue was an import of `java.lang.String`. For some reason IntelliJ imported it.